# Adding int64 and int32 in protobuf

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

How to add elements for int64 and int32 in protobuff

```
message PDBparam
{
  repeated string paramData=1; 
  required int64 HealthID=2; 
  required int32 OccCount=3; 
  optional bytes wci=4;
```

}

To add paramData I can use below function call for string, but what I should use for other 3 parameters.

```
//add -param data
add_paramdata("param_1");
```

Similarly what function call I should use to get data in all these variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the relevant function that `protoc` generates for your file for the HealthID field:

```
 // required int64 HealthID = 2;
  inline bool has_healthid() const;
  inline void clear_healthid();
  static const int kHealthIDFieldNumber = 2;
  inline ::google::protobuf::int64 healthid() const;
  inline void set_healthid(::google::protobuf::int64 value);
```

You use the set_healthid() function to set the healtid, and healthid() returns it. Similar functions will be generated for the other fields.

Since there can be several `paramData`, it's treated a bit different, you need to tell it which of them, given by an index, you want to get or set. e.g. to iterate over all of them:

```
for (int i = 0; i < buf.paramdata_size(); i++) {
     const std::string &pd = buf.paramdata(i);
     //use pd
 }
```

Comment: To store a single byte what datatype should I use, can I use bytes for that

Comment: @Sijith Look in the code generated for your wci field, you set a byte as a char*, or several bytes that's in a std::string, or a void* + a size. You get back the bytes as a std::string

Comment: Slight addition , the set_wci(const char* value) form expects a nul terminated string (so e.g. you can't use that to set a byte value of 0), the other overloads of set_wci are more general.